# binding on change event to group of input fields in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three input fields as below:

```
 <input type="text" name="address" id="address"/>
 <input type="text" name="city" id="city"/>
 <input type="text" name="country" id="country"/>
```

How can i add onChange event to all of these fields at once something like this:

```
$("select the elements with id address,city,country").bind("change", function() {
            //do something
        });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `,` in id selector as @Rory said

OR

add a class to all this and call change function

```
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="className"/>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="className"/>
<input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="className"/>

$('.className').bind("change", function(){
  //your stuff
});
```

**HOWEVER**

since it is an input field.. i recommend you to use..[keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), using `change` you have to click out of the text box to make it fire.

```
$('.className').keyup(function(){
  //your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `,` as you would in CSS to combine selectors. Try this:

```
$("#address, #city, #country").bind("change", function() {
    //do something
});
```

Alternatively you can add a `class` to each element and select that.